# Ionic 4 usar cookies en peticion http

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy usando una api rest un poco antigua. Cuando hago la peticion de logearme me devuelve los datos de la cookie que tengo que almacenar para poder usar el resto de llamadas de la api rest.

Como puedo pasarle una cookie en las llamadas? estoy usando http client.

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Las cookies se añaden automáticamente en cada llamada al servidor. Otra opción es crear la cookie con Javascript y meter los datos, que se enviarán en la siguiente llamada que hagas